# FFmpeg Repeat/loop video two times

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hi I would like to repeat the source video n times.

For example,
If the input source file duration is 5 seconds and repeat 4 times then final video should 20 seconds.

Please specify the command for this
`ffmpeg -i D:\21-03-2018\15271618235b06a3df9d5cb.mp4 -loop 4 D:\21-03-2018\output.mp4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way is via the stream_loop option,

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 3 -i D:\21-03-2018\15271618235b06a3df9d5cb.mp4 -c copy D:\21-03-2018\output.mp4
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify start and end time?

Comment: Not implemented as such.

Comment: @Gyan is there any way I can loop the video for like 3min?

Comment: Add `-t 180` as output option.